# Не включается jit

Tags: php, docker, jit

у меня не включается jit.

Проект работает в связке nginx + php-fpm + docker.

То что выводится в phpinfo() результат файлов из докера.

У меня включён opcache, но при этом мне не надо сбрасывать кэш при изменении кода, и для опции jit задана и память и режим трассировки.

[image: JIT]

Но при этом, опция jit заявлена как отключённая.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядит мой php.ini файл

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING

memory_limit = 1G
upload_max_filesize = 200M
post_max_size = 200M
short_open_tag = On

opcache.enable = 1
opcache.jit = 1255
opcache.jit_debug = 1
opcache.jit_buffer_size = 256M
opcache.enable_cli = 1
opcache.revalidate_freq = 0
opcache.max_accelerated_files = 16229
opcache.memory_consumption = 128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer = 16
opcache.fast_shutdown = 1

pm.max_children = 20
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 15
```

Он находится в _docker/app/php.ini, Dockerfile находится в той же директории

Dockerfile выглядит таким образом

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    apt-utils \
    libpq-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    git

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install bcmath \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install opcache


# Install Redis extension
RUN pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis

# Install Xdebug extension
RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Customize PHP configuration for development
COPY ./_docker/app/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini

# Clean up
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/ /var/tmp/*

# Install composer
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
    --filename=composer \
    --install-dir=/usr/local/bin

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www
```

Пожалуйста, помогите мне настроить включение opcache и jit

Comment: `RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql bcmath gd opcache` - вместо дубирования можно просто пeречислить что ставить, кроме того лучше выносить настройки отдельными файлами а не все пихать в php.ini

Comment: Так что поменяется, расширение встало, phpinfo() всё отдаёт. Я понимаю, что такие конфигурации надо в отдельные файлы выносить, но это мой проект и пока мне без надобности это